# Entering date into a date field

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I need to sendkeys (variable value) in to the element (textbox with text showing 'Expiration Date') below

Below is the html code

```
<div class="input-calendar">
    <input type="text" class="input-calendar-field" placeholder='Expiration 
    Date" value>== $0
```

With `exp_date=driver.find_element_by_class('input-calendar-field').send_keys(expdate)`, I get error below.

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class'
```

With `exp_date=driver.find_element_by_class('input-calendar-field').click()`, I get error below.

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class'
```

How do I get to enter a date in to this filed?

Comment: I think it should be `find_element_by_class_name` not `find_element_by_class`

Comment: see http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Thanks. find_element_by_class_name worked.